# how can i post JSON object through cURL in php

Tags: php, json, curl

How can I post JSON objects to a web service, through cURL in php?

I have an array

```
$data = array('username'=>'abc','password'=>'pass');
```

The webservice which I want to call accepts JSON object, if I convert the $data to JSON with json_encode, its not working for me.

```
$data = json_encode($data);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST      ,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS    ,$data);
```

Am I doing something wrong? or I need any more parameters to set?

Thanks for help in advance.

Tanmay

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
```

to specify that the data is JSON.  The default is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.